# np.mean() and np.std() of norm.pdf()

Tags: python

Why np.mean and np.std() in below code are not equal to 0 and 1 ?

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm
X=np.linspace(-2,2,10)
Y=norm.pdf(X,0,1)
print(np.mean(Y))
print(np.std(Y))
```

Output:

```
0.21936441852687888
0.1235380616222831
```

Comment: This is because you have sampled values from a distribution which will have randomness to it. As you increase the number of samples from 10 -> infinity you will see the mean and variance converge.

Answer (score 1):

Because `Y` represents the PDF of a Gaussian with mean 0 and standard deviation 1, evaluated at points in `X`, which cannot be negative by definition. I think you are confused on what's the difference between a distribution values and its density function.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Y you just created:

```py
# I've taken a bigger X = np.linspace(-2, 2, 10000) for smoothness
plt.plot(X, Y)
plt.show()
```

[image: Density function of a normal distribution N(0,1)]

Y is a discretized version of the **density function** of the normal distribution. This is not a sample of numbers taken from it, so you can't expect its mean or variance to have such values.

**To go further**:

However, you can expect the **integral** of the pdf over [-inf, inf] to be 1 (which is kind of a sum of Y). And indeed:

```py
B = 1e4 # integration bound. Increase it towards +inf to have a better approximation
step = 1e-1
X = np.arange(-B, B, step)
Y = norm.pdf(X, 0, 1)
print(np.sum(Y) * step) # rectangle approx of the integral
# 0.999999999996362
```